# How is that distribution of ROS have?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How is that distribution of ROS have?, This because when installing the lightweight simulator tutorial Understanding ROS nodes, I could not change my distro for alleged distribution is hydro, but it says there is no package or file I'm working with ubuntu 12.04 thanks for your help and attention given

Error message:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-<hydro>-ros-tutorials
Error bash: hydro: No such file or directory
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/124821/how-is-that-distribution-of-ros-have?/) by [felipe](https://answers.ros.org/users/11481/felipe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-01-30

Post score: -2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-30**:
Can you update your question with the exact command and error message that you're seeing?

**Comment by [felipe](https://answers.ros.org/users/11481/felipe/) on 2014-01-30**:
command
sudo apt-get install ros--ros-tutorials

Error
bash: hydro: No such file or directory

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2014-01-30**:
Did you install ROS following the instructions in http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Ubuntu?

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2014-01-30**:
The command should be `$ sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-ros-tutorials´

**Comment by [felipe](https://answers.ros.org/users/11481/felipe/) on 2014-01-30**:
gustavo.velascoh thank you very much for your great help and I could really solve my problem with the help of gustavo.velascoh you are all very friendly. good evening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When replacing <distro> with the name of your distribution, the angle brackets typically delimit the thing to be replaced, and should be removed in the final command. Thus, you should be running:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-ros-tutorials
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8